# Underperforming parameterized query on a linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, linked-server

```
DECLARE @FROMDATE datetime, @TODATE datetime

SET @FROMDATE = getdate()-30
SET @TODATE = getdate()

SELECT col1,col2, col3, datecolumn from [linked_server].[database].[dbo].[view]
WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN @FROMDATE and @TODATE
```

When this query is run locally on the linked_server (SS 2005), it takes approximately 8 seconds.

When I run it from another server (SS2008 R2), it is taking upwards of 9 minutes.

This had been running on the SS 2008 R2 server at comparable speeds to the local query so this underperformance is "new".  I would appreciate any thoughts concerning where I should be looking.

Comment: I would start by updating the statistics on the remote server - you may be getting a bad plan if statistics are out of date.

Comment: Are there any indexes on the table which has the datecolumn column? Your query is probably causing a clustered index scan or table scan, which are both rather slow.

Comment: How often do you rebuild indexes on linked_server?